# Can I use ThreeJS to make 3D game in Facebook Instant Games?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I want to develop a 3D game using ThreeJS. Does facebook support this library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it does support pure javascript code which means you can have access to webgl and install threejs npm library